# Spinner selection- locale change - keep the selected value

Tags: android, localization, android-spinner

hi the question is I want to refresh my activity when user change the selection of the spinner 
I have 3 languages English-Spanish-French.
when select one of them the activity should change the layout to the selected language layout 
.
I have spinner & textView to show a message.

the next code doesn't work with me it restart the activity but then back  language not to wt the user select to the default and its  repeating the restarting of the app :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    cnt=this;
    spin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.language_spinner_login);
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> languageAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(cnt,
                        R.array.lang,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spin.setAdapter(languageAdapter);
          spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {

                    if (pos == 0) {

                       setLocale("fr");
                    } else if (pos == 1) {


                        setLocale("en");
                    } 
     else if (pos == 2) {

                        setLocale("sp");
                    } 

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });

          textview.setText(string.hello_world);
        }

public void setLocale(String lang) {

       Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh =new Intent(cnt, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
    }
```

2-second Q I wanna save the selcted item into spinner next time when the user open the app the spinner selected item should be wt the user selected last time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep selected locale in preference

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
p.edit().putString("selected_locale", locale).commit();
```

and fetch when u need to set it again

```
String locale = p.getString("selected_locale", "");
```

Dont call setLocale() method every time. Since when you try to set the  spinner setLocale will be called again. is that your Problem?

**Edit:**

Try this. http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html

Modify as per your need :)

Comment: yes this is the problem but when should I use setLocale() method ?